# Localizing Titanium Android application

Tags: android, localization, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a completed Titanium Android application (that the developer was not me).
I want to localize it but both the strings and the UI are hard coded in the source code.
The application built in javascript.

The UI is also important because we also want a right-to-left version of the app.

Need to mention that I'm pretty new to the Titanium environment.

**What is the best approach to this task?**

Comment: have you tried reading the [Documentation](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Internationalization)?

Comment: I asked about a general approach not a specific code that required solution.

Comment: I mean, for what reason is the original developer unable to provide source code?  You will not be able to do this without it.

Comment: This is the situation. the original developer not in the development loop anymore for some reason I also don't know. They only can support for specific questions. Any way, My task is not maintainance of the code, just localization, and since I'm new to Titanium I asked what is the best approach. I still don't understand why is the downvote...

Comment: I don't know, as it wasn't me. I'm afraid it is impossible to localise an application without the source code. You should explain this to your customer and refer them to here. You might just be able to change the hard coded strings with a hex editor, but that is fraught with danger, could introduce all kinds of side effects, lead to crashes and so on. For right to left, nothing you can do without hacking. There is no rational solution for you.  You should also explain to your customer that paying someone to develop an app and not having the source code as one of the deliverables is not normal.

Comment: Of course I have the source code (without it I wouldn't ask this question) Maybe this wasn't clear from the beginning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to take the source code and find all the hard coded strings and move them to the il8n/ folder's string.xml file.  You would need to create one of these files in the appropriate language directory with the string that corresponds to the particular hard coded value you want to represent.

For example:

```
var mystring = L('hi_text');
```

In Titanium, this code would go to the language folder (of the device's setting, i.e. English or en folder) and look for an entry like this:

il8n/en folder:

```
<string name="hi_text">Hello</string>
```

If the device was in Spanish language mode, that same code would then look to the il8n/es folder:

```
<string name="hi_text">Hola<string>
```

That would allow you to switch the language, but changing the UI would likely be a significant change to the source code.  In the app.js file, you may attempt to detect the language of the device and branch to completely different logic for the screens.  You could also do this in the particular screen javascript files as well, where you call one creation function for each different language.  You will likely be changing the architecture of the application if it didn't already have that requirement built-in.

Comment: What about UI? If I want to localize the UI such in a rtl locale it will work in rtl and the opposite.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with rtl locales.  What would you want to change?  Give an example.  Are you talking about the way that the screens animate or do you have to align text a different way?

Comment: basically only alignments required. Maybe there is a possibility to export layout files (such) css to the il8n/ folder as I do to the strings? (The specific code is irrelevant because I'm talking about the general method of handling several layouts that depends on the locale, not only rtl to ltr..)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I think you would need to create different layout functions based on if the language was a rtl type language.  Like doLTL() and doRTL().  There should be examples of doing this with different orientations like Portrait and Landscape.  Similar idea.  At runtime you might need to detect the language and call the different layout code.  It really depends how the application was written and how modular it is.  In the new Titanium SDK 3.0+ version, there are new layout options which would probably better fit your situation, but it was just released.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official document : 
https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/125732/localization-not-working